# Login via google and facebook using django-social-auth

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-oauth, facebook-oauth, django-socialauth

I am trying to integrate [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) on my django app which is running on google app engine.

I am trying to implement google-oauth2 and facebook oauth login using django-social-auth.

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '377490210257-****'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = '***********'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_APP_ID = '******'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'xxxx'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
    'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2Backend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

When I try to [login via google oauth](http://prmediastore.appspot.com/login/google-oauth2/), I get the following error:

```
TooManyRedirects at /complete/google-oauth2/
Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

When I try to [login via facebook auth](http://prmediastore.appspot.com/login/facebook), I get the following error:

```
HTTPError at /complete/facebook/
400 Client Error: Bad Request
```

I am not sure whether are there any other configuration that needs to be done to make it run.

Since google app engine doesn't have django-social-auth as the library, I had to manually put all the libraries in the source folder.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you're using Django instead of Jinja2 .. or just because you found the django-social-auth plugin..?

Comment: I have been using django on different projects, so thought of using djaong on GAE. I cannot switch from Django to Jinja2. I have already proceeded a lot with the project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade the version of urllib3, bug is documented here: https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/356